# how to export report using owasp zap session

Tags: zap

Im trying to generate the zap report using the existing session. Im able to run the scan and save those sessions, with that session i need to create a report in either .html or .pdf

The below code can load the session, but report is not generating.

```
#!/bin/bash

ZAP_HOME="/Applications/OWASP ZAP.app/Contents/Java"
ZAP=${ZAP_HOME}/zap.sh

# Getting current timestamp to use it in the session name
timestamp="/Users/xxx/ZAP/January-19-12:50.session";

# Getting the report generated in HTML format
sh "${ZAP}" -daemon  -quickout /Users/jijesh/report.html -session "$timestamp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `-quickout` is only applicable if you've used `-quickurl`.

You can find ZAP's commandline reference here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/cmdline/

For specifics on the `-quick*` options see: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/quick-start/cmdline/

You can find more information about automation with ZAP here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

Really you should avoid using the `-quick*` mechanisms, they're the oldest and least flexible/useful of the ways to automate ZAP. You'd be much better off leveraging the Automation Framework or interacting with the API programmatically.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i was trying something else with zap api, with that im able to generate the report, but the report is empty using curl  curl -o zap-report.html http://localhost:8080/OTHER/core/other/htmlreport/?

Comment: Did your session open successfully? Are there alerts to report?

Comment: yes session is opened, but report seems empty

Comment: Has ZAP actually done anything? Pro tip - if you can use the ZAP GUI then do so - its much easier to debug problems that way as you can see exactly whats going on.